# Client/Server Certificate Authentication: IIS server-side, Blackberry native browser client-side

Tags: authentication, blackberry, certificate

I have a Web application (.NET/SQL) that I'd like to change the authentication scheme from a local SQL-based username/password to a client/server certificate model.

Kicker is that the client devices are Blackberry Bolds (assuming the most recent) and I have no idea whether Blackberries support this method of authentication.

I should note that these devices are not managed by BES (or the organization for that matter): they will be using the native Blackberry browser to connect to a Web application on the public Internet over untrusted wifi and 3G networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the BlackBerry browser has supported this method of authentication since at least OS 4.6 (the first Bold). The issue is getting the appropriate certificate to the device in a way secure enough for your application without BES.

Comment: very cool.  Thanks.  I think I found a method of doing so with Desktop Manager actually.

Comment: Yes, the DM will put certificates on the device, and if you can get them to the desktop computer securely then that's a win.